# Adding label on Image

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hello,

I would like to add a label like second red. I think I can do it with Sizedbox but I can't add it in Container. The second alternative would be make first SCIENCE background color red but in this way label starting immediatly from first letter which I won't like.
any help

```
children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //let's add the height

              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(articles[index].imageUrl!),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
            ),
            // alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 170, left: 10),
                child: const Text('SCIENCE',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
          ),
```

Comment: You want to science word on above of image?

Comment: Did you use "Stack" widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have handled the background using stack, just wrap Text with padding. Or use container padding.

Like

```
  Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text(
                    "SCIENCE",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                ),
```

**Result**

[image: output]

**Full Stack**

```
 SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        width: 600,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/ocean.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Positioned(
              /// set the way you like
              left: 10,
              bottom: 10,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(
                  "SCIENCE",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 22,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I need only change Image.asset with NetworkImage(articles[index].imageUrl!) rest is perfect

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a stack like this

```
 Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //let's add the height

            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(articles[index].imageUrl!),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 5,
          bottom: 10,
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(
                "SCIENCE",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```